# How do I design MVC apps with view auditing in mind?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We're going to be building an application using MVC 4. A key requirement is view-level auditing. In other words, we must be able to show who accessed a view/screen (person details, for example), the parameters to create the view and when the view was accessed. This is a new application so we can do almost whatever needs to be done to address this requirement.

The database will be SQL Server 2008. Data access will include EF 4.x, possibly 5.x but not a sure thing.

My question, how do I get started designing this feature? Are there any sample applications out there?

Comment: @jrummell - We're in design mode and not sure how to get started. I have row and field level auditing implemented on a proof of concept.

Comment: What kind of View are you referring to? MVC View, SQL View, or some other kind of View?

Comment: views refers to pages & screens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mind auditing at view level. I think it is better to audit actions. You can do this using global action filters (for example [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/08/15/asp-net-mvc-3-global-action-filters.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

EF does not work very well with Views.  You might be better of with either a straight ADO.NET persistence layer that you hand code, or Linq2Sql is a little better about using views (you still have to hook them up manually though).  nHibernate would probably be the best ORM to use.

EDIT:

@user1469655 - You have a very fundamental misunderstanding of how MVC works.  The "view" is not a page.  It's a template.  The "page" as you might consider it (ie accessing a specific url) is really a combination of two different things, a route and an action.  An action can cause a specific template (view) to render, but there is not necessarily a 1:1 correlation between action and view.

An "action" is a method of a controller.  This is mapped to a URL by a route.  Typically (but not necessarily), this means something like this:

```
http://www.my.site/controller/action
```

When a user visits this URL, it causes the action method to be called, and potentially for a view to be rendered.  Different actions can render the same view, because this is nothing more than an html template that can be rendered at will by any action method.

So what you want to do depends on what you are actually logging.  It makes no sense whatsoever to log access to the view, because that doesn't actually mean anything.  What you want to do is log access through the action, or possibly even log it through the route.

The simplest way to do this is to use a global action filter that is called before every action, in that filter you can log the information you need to (user id, date, time, action, referrer, whatever).. and it gets called for every action.  It will not, however, get called for ignored routes (such as for content like javascript, images, css, files downloaded directly, etc..).  If you need to log those, then you will need to control access to them via an action.

There's a good tutorial on Action Filters here

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

Comment: @Maess -that's not what I said.  I said EF doesn't work well with Views.  EF assumes that any non-null fields in views are primary keys, which is very inconvenient in most cases.

Comment: EF does no such thing.  In EF the only property assumed to be a PK is Id or [entityname]Id.  If you use a PK of another naming convention you have to configure EF to handle it.

Comment: @Maess - Trust me, it does. I fought with it for days trying to get it to work. Again, this is only the case with Views, not normal tables.  You do realize we're talking about SQL Server views, not the V in MVC, right?

Comment: @Maess - here's a blog that describes the problem and attempts to work around it. http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/08/12/entity-framework-creating-a-model-using-views-instead-of-tables/

Comment: The OP is not talking about db views, he is talking about MVC Views.

Comment: @Maess - That's ridiculous.  Nobody would log access to a view model, that's pointless.  One would log access to the Data, which is the SQL View.  He even mentions the database technology.  There is no valid business reason to interpret it the way you did.

Comment: If a user accesses a "view" (i.e., a screen, page, or MVC View) we need to log it even if no changes are made. The simple act of viewing a page needs to be logged for compliance purposes. Whether that means logging access to a SQL View or the MVC View has not been determined.